# Wireless game controller - polling vs events

Tags: wireless, wifi, remote-control

I'm creating wireless game controller, but I have problem with sending data - should it be in polling mode or event based?

For analog axes I think that polling is better. 100Hz or more polling rate, because analog data can change very often and I want to get responsive feeling.

For buttons I can use polling or events.

1. Polling - pros

It's easier to send one same "data package" every 10ms (100Hz 
polling). With event based data transfer data will have different size 
every time I press button, so I need to parse data on main component.

2. Polling - cons

There is redundancy in data transfer (If button isn't pressed, i'm still sending this information every 10ms).

It is possible that button click **will not be catch** at all (but user would have to click down button for less than 10ms, which I tried and I personally can't do it)

Which option is better? How is this done in other game controllers? Which polling rate will be good enough?

Comment: In the old days the button states were just shifted out continuously via shift register, but I don't know how fast. You'd periodically get an 8- or 16-bit register's worth of button state data. I imagine the designers would have experimented a bit with finding the slowest acceptable transfer rate.

Comment: I would use interrupts for momentary pushbuttons. Polling for analog sticks and toggle switches. Don't forget to work in your debouncing scheme no matter which method you take. Transmission and reading the inputs are separate issues and you need to clear up which it is you are asking about. (i.e. Wirelessly polling the controller to request a wireless transmission is pointless since data is sent frequently)

Comment: There's not nearly enough context to answer this. What is your realtime requirements? How much work does the MCU do besides this? Does it have DMA? What's the ADC sample rate and so on? Are there any hardware filters? You are essentially just asking what's better: tea or coffee.

Comment: @DKNguyen That's just opinions out of the blue. Even the slowest MCU on the market will be able to poll such buttons without a human noticing. Bounce characteristics is what matters here. It's a bad idea to connect buttons to interrupt GPIO in general - it is possible but [you need to know what you are doing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23559522/584518). The vast majority of electronics hobbyists aren't good enough programmers to pull that off, so telling them to use interrupts without any head's up is just bad advise.

Comment: @Lundin Polling doesn't eliminate the need for debouncing and I did mention debouncing.

Comment: @DKNguyen Yes but as shown in that link, debouncing an interrupt-triggering GPIO requires a whole lot more complexity than polling does.

Comment: @Lundin Only if you choose to do software debouncing. Either way, it's well within the realm of practicality.

Comment: @DKNguyen We don't have the schematic so we can only speculate.

Comment: The thing is - I don't really know about realtime requirements and that's why I'm asking for opinions and patterns that are used commonly. I'm using ESP8266 to detect button clicks / read data from sensors (accelerometer) and I'm sending this via UDP to another ESP8266, which then sends data (via UART) to Arduino Micro directly connected to PC USB port (There must be Arduino because ESP8266 can't operate as USB HID controller device). I can use UDP only for polling (send all data via UDP) or mix UDP and TCP (UDP for axes / accelerometer data and TCP for button events).

Comment: Have you evaluated the latency of sending "button presses" via wireless UDP or TCP, then by UART, and then by USB? I fear that the delays in the communication will be unacceptable for game controller.

Comment: @elliot-alderson Currently I have tested moving mouse based on accelerometer orientation. It uses UDP only with 100Hz polling rate. I don't have exact numerical results, but it works very responsive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do what every other controller does, and just send all the buttons in every data package. You only need one bit for each button (rounded up to a whole number of bytes).

This makes it much simpler, because there is no need to make sure that the game has received a change and resend any changes that it didn't receive.

Yes, it will save bandwidth if you only send the changes. Are you short on bandwidth?

Comment: Hi, That's exactly what I have done - because of simplicity. I'm not short on bandwidth that much. And yes, I'm sending all buttons in one 16-bites integer. It looks like that two methods - pooling and events will be good. Pooling is just simpler as you said.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should make a difference between 'scanning' the buttons and sending them.

Scanning I would do very fast, as you say, you cannot press them faster than 10 ms, but maybe others can so maybe you need even a faster scan.

For sending (wirelessly), you can send them only when changed (as long as you know the receiver received it with some return message/confirmation). If there is no confirmation you can send it often (and a missed message will be overwritten some ms later by the latest update).

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Unless you have a lot of buttons it may be easier to just keep sending them, than to design a protocol to make sure the computer has received them.

Comment: @user253751 That's also a good solution (I focused only on receiving/sending data). If there is e.g. only a one way transmission, it's definitely the best.